# Can tuple with list as an element be key in a dictionary python?

Tags: python

Can tuple with list as an element which can be modified at any stage be key in a dictionary?

Comment: Just try if it works. One of the benefits is the REPL which allows playing with the language.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are hashable, and therefore usable as dict keys, if and only if all of their elements are hashable.

This is what you're intuitively expect, and it's easy to test:

```
>>> {(1, 2): 3}
{(1, 2): 3}
>>> {(1, [2]): 3}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

But if you want to know where it's documented, it's in the [**Immutable Sequence Types**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#immutable-sequence-types) section of the **Sequence Types — `list`, `tuple`, `range`** docs:

> The only operation that immutable sequence types generally implement that is not also implemented by mutable sequence types is support for the `hash()` built-in.
>
> This support allows immutable sequences, such as `tuple` instances, to be used as `dict` keys and stored in `set` and `frozenset` instances.
>
> **Attempting to hash an immutable sequence that contains unhashable values will result in `TypeError`.**